# kubernetes: How to set active namespace for all kubectl commands?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am working on kubernetes cluster. In my cluster i am having 3 namespaces.

- Default
- Staging
- Production

At a time when i want to work on staging namespace.

In every kubectl command i have to pass namespace

```
kubectl get pods -n staging

kubectl get deployment -n staging
```

Is there any way to set active namespace at a time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=<insert-namespace-name-here>
# Validate it
kubectl config view --minify | grep namespace:
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#setting-the-namespace-preference

Comment: yes it will work with minikube @automationDeveloper. check running `kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=staging`

Answer (score 4):

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=<insert-namespace-name-here>
```

Refer [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

Also you can use [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) plugin

Answer (score -1):

you can edit any config with this command :

```
kubectl edit configmaps
```

edit namespace.